# Laravel table field with _id saved as integer when the field type is varchar

Tags: laravel, model, foreign-keys, eloquent

Trying to save a big integer as string on varchar field but it is saved as negative integer.
Here is my fields array:

`Array
    (
        [user_id] => 1
        [account_id] => 7
        [title] => Some Title
        [ad_account_id] => 7855107227
        [is_active] => 1
    )`

Database table name: ad_accounts
Here ad_account_id is varchar(191) but the value is saved as `-734827365`

I know this is due to laravel assuming the field as integer because the field has `_id` at the end.

How can I tell laravel to  stop assuming the field as integer and treat it as varchar/string?

Comment: is there any error?

Comment: show us how you are saving data to db??

Comment: The issue is php issue.
Here is the answer:

```
[ad_account_id] => (string) 7855107227
```

We have to cast `7855107227` to string.